# Curl Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded special characters in body

Tags: javascript, curl

I'm struggling  with curl post request in jsx script file. Issue occurs when I'm sending body with special characters, if there are special character such as $ & ' it strips out whatever is after it. Is there any way to escape those and send through?

```
var postRequest = [
            'POST ' + url + ' HTTP/1.1',
            'Host: ' + quad.ms.global.host,
            'User-Agent: Adobe InDesign',
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length: ' + requestData.length,
            '',
            requestData, 
            ''];
```

Example of the request: username=testuser$&'^-@domain.com

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: Or [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). `console.log(encodeURI("username=testuser$&'^-@domain.com"));` vs `console.log("username=" + encodeURIComponent("testuser$&'^-@domain.com"))`